# Good Protocol Practice/Template for sockets?

Tags: algorithm, sockets, tcp, protocols

Right, I'm looking for some more advanced flexible protocols to implement to my sockets.
I'll be transferring data, video, audio and text through the **single same TCP socket.**

The current protocol I'm using is this: **Get data length and header. Write it out.
Then write out the actual data. The other side will read the first bytes of the length and header and then receive that much.**

You'll notice this is not good as I can only simultaneously send one type of data on the socket.

So how exactly can I improve on this?

Much appreciated.

Comment: "*... as I can only simultaneously send one type of data on the socket.:*" Multiplexing different contents wouldn't make it's transmission faster. One socket, one stream. How do you think not sending one thing after another could make things better?

Comment: I don't want to make it faster. The problem is multiplexing itself. I don't mind if all 4 contents are laggy, but my problem is that one is stalled after another and cannot achieve it.

Comment: So why not use 4 connections transmitting in parallel though? Or chop you data into pieces, each piece prefixed with a header stating size and type and a unique piece-id. Such pieces can then be transmitted in any order you like.

Comment: Oh I see, I think I got you. I've split everything into small data pieces of 4096 bytes. I've also synchronized the sockets on separate threads using the critical section and added each packet a size and type. The other side collects them and rebuilds them; creating the illusion of all 4 streaming at the same time and that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending different types of data as your payload, then you'll probably want to distinguish the type in the header that you're writing out. Other than that, there's not really any rules about making up your own protocol, that's half the fun! It all comes down to what's useful to your software.

Comment: Of course, but don't you agree that some protocols have certain advantages over others? I'm not entirely happy with mine and I'm looking for an improvement...

Comment: You need to describe your protocol more than "I write a length, header, and data" if you want more feedback... that summarized virtually every protocol in existence.